# inner product vs projected inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For two vector, $\displaystyle b_{1} ,\ b_{2}$ and a matrix $\displaystyle A$:

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
A\ \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1\times n} ,\ b_{1} ,\ b_{2} \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1} ,\ 
\end{array}$

I'm wondering what's the relationship between $\displaystyle < b_{1} ,\ b_{2}> \ $ and $\displaystyle < Ab_{1} ,Ab_{2}> $ ?

Comment: There can be, under certain assumption on $A$, more specifically on $A^TA$.

Comment: What about the assumption? And what would be the relation?

Comment: Since $\langle Ab_1, Ab_2 \rangle = \langle b_1, A^{\top}A b_2 \rangle$ you need to know something about $A^{\top}A$ in order to say anything.

Comment: why would $\langle Ab_1, Ab_2 \rangle == \langle b_1, A^TAb_2 \rangle$ ?